# Display color calibration

Tags: intel-graphics

Where can I find an option or an application to display color calibration as in Windows 7?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found something in Application-> System tools-> Preference-> Display

Then you should have something like Color (where you  see keyboard, power management, printers). Open that thing up, select your display and then click properties. In my case it offered to install packages automatically libicc2, libcolord-gtk1, argyll, libimdi0.
Ubuntu 14.04, gnome-session-fallback.

Alex.